# CSV data streaming using kafka connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a business event that come in CSV file format which needs to be appended to database (in our case snowflake) using  Kafka.

Do we need to convert the csv file to JSON format (using python) and then pass the values to kafka-producer topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html).

1. Read from CSV file into Kafka using a connector such as [Kafka Connect spooldir](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-spooldir/index.html) (see [example](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-in-action-enriching-csv-events-with-data-from-rdbms-into-AWS/))
2. Stream from Kafka topic to Snowflake using [Snowflake's connector for Kafka Connect](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector.html) (see [example](https://rmoff.net/2019/11/20/streaming-data-from-sql-server-to-kafka-to-snowflake-with-kafka-connect/))

Learn more about Kafka Connect in [this talk](https://talks.rmoff.net/DQkDj3/from-zero-to-hero-with-kafka-connect).

Comment: Thanks Robin for sharing the info. Will look into it and get back to you incase of any concerns.

Comment: Please post a new question, with full details of your installation, version, etc. thanks.

Comment: Robin, i have downloaded spool dir plugin and unzipped in share/kafka/plugins/<pluginfolder>. Added the plugin path to below properties files: 1) /etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties 2) /etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties and in /etc/kafka/connect-file-source.properties gave the fine name but when i start service "connect-standalone ./kafka/connect-standalone.properties ./schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties ./etc/kafka/connect-file-source.properties" i get key.converter.schema.registry.url=localhost:8081} contains no connector type error. Can you help me

Comment: @RobinMoffatt The documentation for kafka connect spooldir says "it is only suitable for files that are complete; if the file is still being written to by another process then it wouldn’t be appropriate to use this." In our case the CSV file is continuously being updated with new rows. Is there a connector for this use-case?

Comment: @AaditiJain it sounds like a CSV file is totally the wrong way to exchange data - why not stream data from the process that's writing to the CSV file continuously into Kafka directly instead?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Thank you for your answer. Can you please elaborate on why do you suggest to not use CSV for data exchange? The idea is to only read from the CSV (and not write back to it).